# how do I count the data plus list the data

Tags: sql, oracle

I am very very new to SQL

For example, a student with 2 As and 3 Cs will produce two records: sid, A, 2; sid, C, 3. If the student doesn't have any grades I don't want them listed

```
select sid, count(grade) from enrollments
group by sid
```

Example of what I want:

```
sid          grade
123          A,2; C,3
456          A,3; B,1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work for you.

```
select sid, 
    listagg(gradecount, '; ') within group (order by gradecount) as grade
from (
    select sid, grade || ',' || count(1) as gradecount
    from enrollments
    where grade is not null
    group by sid, grade
    ) studentgradecount
group by sid;
```

If it seems confusing, try running the inner query by itself to see what it does:

```
select sid, grade || ',' || count(1) as gradecount
from enrollments
where grade is not null
group by sid, grade
```